# AngularJs $http.post -> Error: Unexpected Request POST ; no more request expected

Tags: angularjs, curl, xmlhttprequest

I've got a working curl request here:

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://mybackend.somedomain.com/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Now I try to translate this to my angularJs (ionicframework) frontend.
(The php-backend is on a different server, so this might maybe have something to do with CORS, too, though I don't know how)

In my frontend I try:

```
var username = 'testclient';
var password = 'testpass';
var url = 'http://mybackend.somedomain.com/token.php';
var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: url,
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

This results in something weird, the POST request isn't executed, but instead I get the error message:

```
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://mybackend.somedomain.com/token.php No more request expected
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Do you try that in a unit test ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a mistake in your Angular `POST`, your data is encoded as JSON instead of what you claim in headers `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. First you should change your code to below.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: $.param({
      username: username,
      password: password
    }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
```